# AWS Lambda: Unique Key generator for s3 files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a AWS lambda function running some code and then saving a json to a s3 bucket.

Currently, my formatting is using the datetime package to grab the current date.

`now = str(datetime.today())`

I am then formatting the csv to 
`'payrollcompensation_streams/{}_{}.json'.format('pega_payrollcompensation_raw',now))`

What I want to do is everytime this AWS Lambda function runs generate an unique key of an integer instead of a datetime.

Instead of this: `pega_payrollcompensation_raw_2020-03-05 00:00:00.0000`
This: `pega_payrollcompensation_raw_1`

Then the next time

`pega_payrollcompensation_raw_2`

Comment: Do the unique names _need_ to be sequential? Otherwise, you could simply use a UUID. What is particularly "wrong" with the timestamp naming method currently being used?

Comment: Each lambda function pulls a raw json of a table in a system. Sometimes that table changes, I am trying to capture the “delta/offset” between the latest data pull and the one prior to calculate the difference. I was going to use a counter to take the current number -1 to grab the right file in s3.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `timestamp()` method for your unique key?

For example:

```
>>> datetime.today().timestamp()
1583449231.642402
```

Comment: I am trying to measure the difference between two api pulls about a day apart. To measure the offset amongst each day and then save that as a file.

Answer (score 1):

In case of using Lambda for this task you need to save state somewhere. Best fit for your case is DynamoDB. You need to set some sort of counter there and receive value from counter  first. Be careful with concurrency.